# Using Auto Layout, how do I make two labels on the same "line" be dynamic in their widths (adjusting with how wide each one needs to be)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

Say I have two UILabels, one is a URL and one is a timer:

```
[http://website.com/link/to/specific/story] [9m 42s]
```

But the "timer" UILabel changes width a lot. Sometimes it is just `12s` for example, other times it is `125h 32m 8s`. There's a lot of variability. I want the timer UILabel to take up *as much width as it needs* and the URL label to *take up the rest*. This means if the timer is longer, shorter URLs, etc.

How do I do this in Auto Layout? Preferably in Interface Builder?

Comment: Intrinsic content size + priority

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You should set the compression resistance, URL label must have lower value;

Set the horizontal space between labels to constant (for example zero or default);

Set width for each label and select "less than" or "greater that" relation, these values set limits for shrinking/expanding of the view.

Comment: @DougSmith in your project you did not perform steps 2 and 3.

Comment: Sorry, I pressed enter :)
@DougSmith in your project you did not perform steps 2 and 3.
I have modified your project http://cl.ly/0b1Q2R1R1W1v
Here is what I did: created correct horizontal constraints: from superview to 1st label, from 1st label to 2nd label, and from 2nd label to superview. This fixes "paddind". Then I pinned width for each label and made it "greater than" and "less than" so that width could change. I set width for 1s label >=100 and for 2nd - 50<=width<=100. Now that perfectly works (try to change text of 2nd label)

Comment: There's constraint warnings in that project though.

Comment: @DougSmith Actually I used IB in Xcode5 for the first time :)
Here is the project that I created in Xcode4, same steps, no ambiguous layout: http://cl.ly/44183I3w0N0j
Must be something new in Xcode5...

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! This answer completely solved my problem. I had changed the priority, but not the compression resistance.

Answer (score 12):

This is where compression resistance becomes important. Since the URL label needs to shrink first (in order to accommodate the space for the timer label), the compression resistance of the URL label should be lower than the compression resistance of the timer label (in horizontal direction, of course). You can easily set this attribute in IB.

[image]

Comment: Do I give the labels set widths though? How do I make one be willing to overtake the other?

Comment: No, don't give them widths, let them keep their intrinsic content size.

Comment: If I remove the width constraint, I get insufficient constraint warnings. These are the constraints I have on it as is, what else should I be doing with it? http://i.imgur.com/DIfF8S9.png

Comment: Remove the height. If you don't give it a width or a height, intrinsic content size is assumed. If you give it one of the two, you need to provide the other one as well. It would be nicer if it assumed the intrinsic content width if no width is given and the intrinsic content height if no height is given, but that's not how it works currently.

Comment: What are the warnings? You may have to update your frames because the label sizes are different now.

Comment: Okay, so I have two UILabels both 9pt away from the top of the cell. It looks like this now: http://i.imgur.com/qAFFinF.png I have

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39575/discussion-between-scott-and-doug-smith)