# AutoLayout how to auto expand label

Tags: ios, autolayout

What are the correct constraints to make a label auto expand it's width for a change in text length, as well as push neighbor label to the side?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Auto Layout, how do I make two labels on the same "line" be dynamic in their widths (adjusting with how wide each one needs to be)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19470156/using-auto-layout-how-do-i-make-two-labels-on-the-same-line-be-dynamic-in-the)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should just work if you don't specify a width for the labels. It will set the size based upon the content. Give `Label3` and `Label4` constraints to place them vertically. Give `Label4` a trailing constraint to superview. Give `Label3` a trailing constraint to `Label4` leading.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I realized that since I'm using a view inside a UIScrollView it gets really confusing if not all constraints are set